# How to make circular reveal effect when theme changed? (Like in Telegram or VK)

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation, telegram, vk

I am using [DayNight](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) theme in my application. And I have a button that changes the theme. In VK and Telegram app there is a beautiful reveal animation that changes the theme without restarting activity or something like that.

I have tried to make that with [reveal animation implementation](https://medium.com/@daniele.orlando/beautiful-circular-reveal-animation-on-android-1b5aaca2dd1f) in different ways, but it doesn't work or working bad in some cases with AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(...). All examples with that reveal animation are for ActivityA -> ActivityB, but I just need to update theme without starting any activity.

And one more thing: AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode recreates my activity, so do I need a custom theme changing implementation?

And main question: how to create that animation with theme changing?

Examples:

[Telegram (From Dark to Light)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gQix.jpg)

[Telegram (From Light to Dark)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVl4a.jpg)

[VK (From Light to Dark)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nef2G.jpg)

[VK (From Dark to Light)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIXON.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

since telegram is an open source app you can find the code -> line 3154: [github](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/dd07a925ee3f25307808b263f775266c4cf6444d/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/LaunchActivity.java).
it seems that it converts layout into bitmap and use it with an existing imageView to animate circular reveal

Comment: what will be the value of args[2] in code?

Comment: @basaveshwarlamture perhaps the coordinates of theme toggle button

Comment: the question is how telegram shows an ImageView on entire screen even status bar?

Comment: args[2] found in DrawerProfileCell.java - method: switchTheme()